# Using Google Colab , GPU Plaftorm not found error

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, google-colaboratory, opencl

I use OpenCl for parallel computing via Colab, when trying to get information about platform using

clGetPlatformIDs(1, NULL, &num_platforms);

i get error = -1001.
can anybody tell me what this meaning and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found my answer here:
[can not use lightgbm gpu in colab : LightGBMError: No OpenCL device found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981883/can-not-use-lightgbm-gpu-in-colab-lightgbmerror-no-opencl-device-found/76092824#76092824)

```
!sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460 nvidia-cuda-toolkit clinfo
!apt-get update --fix-missing
```

The OpenCL driver for NVDIA are not installed by default